# what are differences between language array and std::array initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization

std::array supports aggregate initialization, but what is the problem here? If code (1) is used, both vc10.0 and g++ 4.7.2 complain that too many initializers. But if I use code (2) instead, everything is OK.

```
#include <array>

struct elem_t {  char c;  unsigned n;};

struct my_struct_t
{
  int i;
  // std::array<elem_t, 2> a; // (1) cause error
  // elem_t a[2]; // (2) ok
};

int main()
{
  std::array<int, 3> ai[] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; // ok

  my_struct_t var[] =
  {
    { 0, { {'a',1U}, {'b',2U}} }, // in question?
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extra braces -- you need one extra pair for the `array` itself:

```
my_struct_t var[] = { { 0, { { { 'a', 1 } } } }
                    , { 1, { { { 'c', 3 } } } }
};

//                  ^-  mystruct[]
//                     ^-  mystruct
//                         ^-  array
//                           ^-  elem_t[2]
//                             ^-  elem_t
```

The braces can be collapsed at the top level, but this may either be a situation where collapse isn't permitted, or compiler support may just not be there yet.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But this code will not be compiled if I use (1) instead of (2), gcc complains that "错误：类型‘char’的标量初始化带花括号".

Comment: sorry, I mean that "this code will not be compiled if I use (2) instead of (1) ...".

Comment: gcc complains "error: initialization 'char' type scalar with brace".

Comment: Is there any way to make the line marked with "in question" correct under both in case (1) and (2) ?

Comment: @jgx: To the best of my knowledge "no", but I may very well be wrong. I never understand the brace collapsing rules. Double-check them, and then make sure you have a conforming compiler. It might be possible to omit some of the braces and thus make the same syntax work for both types.

Comment: That said, the fully braced version of the first line is `std::array<int, 3> ai[] = { { {1, 2, 3} }, { {4, 5, 6} } };`. Both your version and the even more collapsed `std::array<int, 3> bi[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };` produce warnings in GCC.

Comment: sadly, these braces depend on implementation details of std::array . An implementation of std::array is not required to have a 2-depth aggregation.